# Cancel existing calls to the api when doing findQuery emberjs and ember data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a input field which does a live search. It is set so that for every key press it does a store.findQuery which fires an api request. I've noticed as using it that I need to cancel the  pending ajax calls to the api as each new findQuery is executed. As there ends up being loads of request that are irrelevant now as the search query has changed. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way to do it.  The ajax call itself isn't returned to you for this type of use.  I would recommend debouncing your find requests to avoid making a ton of useless requests.

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  foo:undefined,
  callsToSearch: 0,
  actualSearch: 0,
  watchFoo: function(){
    this.incrementProperty('callsToSearch');
                  //context, method,     time that must elapse before calling method
    Em.run.debounce(this, this.doSearch, 300);
  }.observes('foo'),
  doSearch: function(){
    this.incrementProperty('actualSearch');
    // do the actual search here
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ciyebaqo/1/edit

Comment: There's a better way for this use Ember.run.debounce
Eg: https://gist.github.com/gryzzly/50d6b78dd54bc2468d7a